# Intermittent Request Failures with Vercel Postgres and Next.js #554

Tags: next.js, vercel

I am experiencing intermittent issues with Vercel Postgres when making requests from a Next.js application. The behavior is inconsistent: sometimes the requests work as expected, but other times they fail without any clear reason.

- Consistent Direct Database Queries: When I execute queries directly
  in the database, they always work without any issues.
- Inconsistent Behavior in Next.js: However, when making the same
  queries from my Next.js application, the results are unpredictable.
  Sometimes they succeed, and other times they fail.

This inconsistent behavior is challenging to debug, as there are no apparent errors or patterns to these failures. I am looking for any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve or further diagnose this issue.

This request sometimes works and sometines doesnt, I dont receive any error messages.

```
"use server";

import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres";

export async function abrirConversacion(conversacionId) {
  try {
    const resultado = await sql`
      UPDATE conversaciones SET estado = 'abierto' WHERE id = ${conversacionId};
    `;
    console.log("Resultado de la consulta:", resultado);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error en abrirConversacion:", error);
    return false;
  }
}
```

On the nextjs component:

```
import { abrirConversacion } from "@/lib/data";

const handleAbrirConversacion = async () => {


    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await abrirConversacion(convId);
      setEstado("abierto");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error al abrir la conversación: ${error}`);
    }
    setLoading(false);
    setOpen(false);
};
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it using revalidateTag and unstable_cache.
Explained here:

```
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidateTag
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/unstable_cache
```